# Unity исправить код с андройд управления

Tags: c#, unity3d

игра 2D, присутствует такой код, управление используется под андройд, как изменить, чтобы все выполнялось точно так же, но только с мышкой? Уже много разных способов перепробовал, но ничего не придумал. P.S СКРИП РАБОТАЕТ ТАК: если игрок нажимает на модельку, он может ее перенести в любую сторону, и там отпустить.

```
public class Mouse : MonoBehaviour
{

    bool moveAllowed;
    Collider2D col;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        col = GetComponent<Collider2D>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.touchCount > 0)
        {
            Touch touch = Input.GetTouch(0);
            Vector2 touchPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(touch.position);

            if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Began)
            {
                Collider2D touchedCollider = Physics2D.OverlapPoint(touchPosition);
                if (col == touchedCollider)
                {
                    moveAllowed = true;
                }
            }

            if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Moved)
            {
                if (moveAllowed)
                {
                    transform.position = new Vector2(touchPosition.x, touchPosition.y);
                }
            }

            if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Ended)
            {
                moveAllowed = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

В данном случае, советую ознакомиться с методом `Camera.ScreenToWorldPoint (Input.mousePosition);`, он позволяет вам получить координаты клика мыши.
т.е. вместо `touchPosition.x` вы можете сделать так:
`Vector2 mouse = Camera.ScreenToWorldPoint (Input.mousePosition);`
Вы создаёте вектор с координатами мыши.
И позже можно использовать `mouse.x` или же `mouse.y`
Если вам нужен более подробный ответ, и целая программа, на это уйдёт время..
Этот ответ устраивает?

Answer (score 1):

```
using System;
using UnityEngine;

public class MyInputs : MonoBehaviour {

    private Action _inputUpdate;
    private bool _mousePress;

    private void Awake () {
        if (Application.platform == RuntimePlatform.Android || Application.platform == RuntimePlatform.IPhonePlayer)
            _inputUpdate = UpdateInputTouch;
        else
            _inputUpdate = UpdateInputMouse;
    }

    private void Update () {
        _inputUpdate.Invoke();
    }

    private void UpdateInputTouch () {
        if (Input.touches.Length > 0) {
            Touch Touch0 = Input.touches[0];
            switch (Touch0.phase) {
                case TouchPhase.Began:
                    InputDown(Touch0.position);
                    break;
                case TouchPhase.Ended:
                    InputUp(Touch0.position);
                    break;
                case TouchPhase.Moved:
                    InputMove(Touch0.position);
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    private void UpdateInputMouse () {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) {
            InputDown(Input.mousePosition);
            _mousePress = true;
        } else if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0)) {
            InputDown(Input.mousePosition);
            _mousePress = false;
        } else if (_mousePress)
            InputMove(Input.mousePosition);
    }

    private void InputDown (Vector2 position) {

    }

    private void InputUp (Vector2 position) {

    }

    private void InputMove (Vector2 position) {

    }
}
```